# Looking for azure IoT connected factory demo

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central

We are looking for azure IoT connected solution architecture. How each component is used and why used...

Also we are looking for live demo. may I know who will provide

https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-connected-factory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/quickstart-connected-factory-deploy

Answer (score 0):

> Also we are looking for live demo. may I know who will provide

You will need to deploy the solution yourself. The [link you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/quickstart-connected-factory-deploy?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034) describes the steps you need to take. If you don't need a working solution, but just want the visuals, you can check out [this page](https://demos.azureiotsolutions.com/demos/connectedfactory?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034).

As for the architecture, you mentioned you want to know *why* each component is used. All of the used parts are explained in the [IoT reference architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/iot?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). If you read that document, the resources used for this demo will become quite clear. Because this is a demo, the VM used in the solution hosts all the simulated devices.